# Login failed for user - Godaddy database connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hosting

I bought a GoDaddy plan which comes with unlimited SQL Server databases. I have deployed an ASP.NET website and created a database but I am having a problem when I am trying to connect with it. They have this MyLittleAdmin database management tool which does not let me do anything like creating users or roles.

My connection string looks like this

```
"Data Source=DBserverID;Initial Catalog=DBname Integrated Security=False; User ID=userID; Password=password; Connect Timeout=30; Encrypt=False; Packet Size=4096" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient".
```

Whenever I try to use the forms on the website that are connected to the database, I get this error:

> Login failed for user

I have also trying to the database from my computer but it does not work as well.

Comment: Normally when you create a database using Godaddy there is an option to create a new user to associate with database. Are you using that newly created user in your web.config?

Comment: Yes, i have added that users login info to the connectionstring.

Comment: I suggest you reach out to GoDaddy technical support with your issue